# Waiting for an programmatic key press to be processed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, synchronous, cgeventtap

Someone posted a snippet of code for programmatically pressing a key :

```
- (void)postCommandAndKey:(CGKeyCode)key {

    CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);

    CGEventRef keyDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, key, TRUE);
    CGEventSetFlags(keyDown, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
    CGEventRef keyUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, key, FALSE);

    CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, keyDown);
    CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, keyUp);

    CFRelease(keyUp);
    CFRelease(keyDown);
    CFRelease(source);

}
```

This is not synchronous. What would be a proper way to make sure the key press has been processed?

I thought of using a subsequent dummy key press, but all key combinations could be in use I suppose. My goal is to programmatically copy/paste data in the currently active application without using Accessibility Programming.

Comment: You can't know how the app processes key presses.

Comment: Okay, assuming I just want to force the active app to copy what's selected, is it possible to make sure that action has been processed?

Comment: No, you don't know what the app is doing. Maybe it's impossible to copy. The only thing you can do is wait untill the other app probably processed the event and hope for the best.

Comment: Thanks, Willeke.